# how do i define the $db? Notice: Undefined variable: db

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

However since i am not too familiar with oop in php. i am not sure what i need to define the $db variable as, in order to query my database properly. Is their a way i can edit this code, so it sidesteps the $db and uses a different approach, the code is using ajax to load more posts. The error is on line 24

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#loadmorebutton").click(function (){ 
    $('#loadmorebutton').html(''); 
$.ajax({ 
    url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"), 
    success: function(html){ 
        if(html){ 
            $("ul#posts").append(html); 
            $('#loadmorebutton').html('Load More'); 
        }else{ 
            $('#loadmorebutton').replaceWith('No more posts to show.'); 
        } 
    } 
}); 
}); 
}); 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<?php 
if($posts = $db->get_results("SELECT id,text FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10")) { 
echo '<ul id="posts">'; 
foreach($posts as $post) { 
    echo '<li class="postitem" id="'.$post->id.'">'.$post->text.'</li>'; 
} 
echo '</ul>'; 
} 
?> 
<button id="loadmorebutton">Load More</button> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**Load more**

```
<?php 
if($_GET['lastid']){ 
if($posts = $db->get_results("SELECT id,text FROM posts WHERE id < ".$db-    >escape($_GET['lastid'])." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10")) { 
    foreach($posts as $post) { 
        echo '<li class="postitem" id="'.$post->id.'">'.$post->text.'</li>'; 
    } 
} 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking where you copied it *from*?

Comment: I'd suggest not blindly copy-pasting code that does database interaction. It's (a) unlikely to work for your needs and (b) skipping fundamental understanding you need to actually create a database-driven app.

Comment: "how do i define the $db? Notice: Undefined variable: db"@ I don't know. We can't just guess what your code is. If you're going to copy-and-paste code, it's best to understand what it does first. I'd suggest reading up on OOP PHP. Best of luck. Relative username btw "come2gether". Indeed.

Comment: Are you using the [WPDB](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class from wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to prove complicated if you are not used to Object Oriented PHP but you need to construct your objects. The MySQLi class [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) for instance, takes user, password, database, etc and then knows where it should connect to.

Before you can use stuff like $db->get_results, you need to construct your DB object. Now I don't recognize the get_results function so I presume it is a custom built DB class. You should see the documentation for that specific class if you want to know what to do.

Comment: ok, i may be able to alter the code using what i already have.

Answer (score 0):

Code seems complicated, but if you want to writing like that `$db->get_results`. You have to make a  Database class in the constructor of that you setup database connection using hostname, user, database and password.

After that you define a method **get_result** in that class, and then you create object of that class like `$dg=new Database();` and then you can use `$db->get_result`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than teach you - it'd take too long for an answer here, have a read through PHP's OO pages: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

It won't take you long, and will help you understand the basics, and help fix any problems you'll keep coming across using OO code.